# add a character in front of every element in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, math

I am making a calculator that factors a number. Currently, the list looks like this for the positive number `12`:
 `[1,12,2,6,3,4,4,3,6,2,12,1]`
 I want to change the list, so it looks like this:
`[-1,-12,-2,-6,-3,-4,-4,-3,-6,-2,-12,-1]`.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why the down votes? Is my question not clear enough?

Comment: you have asked two question in one post which is frowned upon, very odd that neither of them explained that in a comment though.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make a copied list with negative values you can use list comprehension:

```
factors = [1,2,3,4,6,12]
negatives = [-item for item in factors]
```

to add it to the original list use the `+=` notation:

```
factors += [-item for item in factors]
```

---

To make each other item negative you can use a basic loop:

```
edited = []
for i in range(len(factors)):
    if i%2:#for odd indices
        edited.append(factors[i])
    else:
        edited.append(-factors[i])
```

this can also be compressed with list comprehension:

```
edited = [factors[i] if i%2 else -factors[i] for i in range(len(factors))]
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a bunch! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Don't we need to increment `i` for it to work? It keeps giving me an empty list.

Comment: `range(len(factors))` deals with incrementing `i`, the second part will give you an empty list if `factors` is initially empty, is that maybe the issue?

Comment: in the first part no indices are needed since you are directly iterating over the elements of the list

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1,12,2,6,3,4,4,3,6,2,12,1]

for x in l[:]: l.append(-x)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `a` is the original list:

```
from itertools import chain, imap
from operator import neg

chain(a, imap(neg, a))
```

`chain` creates, in a lazy way, a generator containing two (or more) lists chained together (one after the other). `imap` is the lazy version of `map`.  The result is a generator that returns the elements of the original list followed by the elements of the negated list.

The lazy approach is very important when dealing with large volumes of data, e.g. 2GB lists. The accepted solution will create a second list, containing the negatives, and then a third list of twice the size, when concatenating the two lists. This becomes even more noticeable if it is not necessary to iterate over the entire list.

Generators are awesome.